# Expected value of sin of brownian motion

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am having trouble finding $E[X_t]$, where $X_t = \sin(B_t)$ and $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. I have learned a little about Ito integrals but I don't think I really understand how to use them.

Here is my approach at the moment:

$$E[X_t] =E[\sin(B_t)] =\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt {2\pi t} } \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^\frac{-(x)^2}{2t} \sin(x) dx\right)\bigg\rvert_{x=B_t}$$

Is this the right approach? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Here $t$ is a fixed number.  Then this is not an Ito integral, it is an ordinary expectation.

Comment: First figure out the distribution of $B_t$ (for any fixed time $t$). Note that the distribution is symmetric about $0$ and $\sin$ is an odd function.

Comment: The integral you wrote is some bizzarre mess: $dB_t$ refers to stochastic integration. Change $B_t$ to $x$ throughout.

Comment: personally I would use the complex exponential expression for the sine, the expectation will follow directly from the characteristic function of a gaussian r.v.

Answer (score 4):

If you've seen Ito's formula, then you can show that 
$$
\sin(B_t) =\sin(B_0)-{1\over 2}\int_0^t\sin(B_s)\,ds+M_t,
$$
where $(M_t)$ is a martingale with $M_0=0$. Define $g(t):=E[\sin(B_t)]$; taking expectations in the above, assuming that $B_0=x$ (constant):
$$
g(t)=g(x)-{1\over 2}\int_0^t g(s)\,ds,\qquad t\ge 0.
$$
Differentiate this to obtain an ODE for $g$ that you can easily solve.

Comment: May I ask why we could move the expectation inside the integral? Is it always true that $$E \left [\int_0^t f(B_s) ds \right] = \int_0^t E \left[f(B_s) \right] ds$$?

Comment: This is okay by Fubini’s theorem, because $\sin$ is a bounded function.